# Not able to understand why this code yield this output

Tags: javascript

I am doing a react course online. In there after function chaining topic, there was an mcq to predict the output. The code is:

```js
function job() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject();
  });
}

let promise = job();

promise

  .then(function() {
    console.log('Success 1');
  })

  .then(function() {
    console.log('Success 2');
  })

  .then(function() {
    console.log('Success 3');
  })

  .catch(function() {
    console.log('Error 1');
  })

  .then(function() {
    console.log('Success 4');
  });
```

But why does this code yield `Error 1,Success 4` as output?

Answer (score 2):

`.catch` will result in passing a resolved Promise to the next step of the chain - unless the `.catch` handler itself throws. That is, given any:

```
.catch(someCallback)
.then(someFn);
```

Unless `someCallback` throws an error (which would result in a rejected Promise, that could be called by a `.catch` further down the line), no matter the situation otherwise, `someFn` will always run.

This is one of the reasons that many choose to put `.catch`s at the very end of a Promise chain - it makes the control flow easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
function job() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject();
  });
}

let promise = job();
```

your promise is the result of job(), if you see your promise is rejected via `reject()`, it means it will go through to `.catch` , and since catch also return a promise, it will go to all `then`s after catch